# Unable to draw into a new PDF with Cocoa/Swift/Quartz

Tags: swift, cocoa, pdf, quartz-graphics

I'm trying create a simple command line app with Swift that will create a new PDF, draw into it, and save the PDF to disk. Below is a bare-bones version of my code:

```
// main.swift
import Cocoa

let fileName = "test.pdf"

func getPath() -> NSURL? {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    do {
        let dir = try fileManager.URLForDirectory(
          NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,
          inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask,
          appropriateForURL: nil,
          create: false
        )
        return dir.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

let context = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(getPath(), nil, nil)
CGPDFContextBeginPage(context, nil)

let path = NSBezierPath(rect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
NSColor.greenColor().set()
path.fill()

CGPDFContextEndPage(context)
CGPDFContextClose(context)
```

When running this code it creates a new `test.pdf` file in my `~/Documents` directory, as expected, but it's just a blank 8.5x11 page. Any drawing code fails with this error: `<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0.`

The code samples for creating and drawing into a PDF that I can find are all quite old. They certainly aren't Swift and they also tend to use Quartz C APIs so I'm feeling a bit lost at this point.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Erik, I stumbled upon this needing a guide on how to make a paginated PDF. Would you mind posting the code you used in the end as a new answer down below? That would be immensely helpful to me!

Comment: I'm looking to write some text onto a PDF, paginated into letter-size pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two worlds here. CoreGraphics and high-level Cocoa drawing calls. To make the Cocoa drawing work, you need to create an NSGraphicsContext based on the CoreGraphics one and make it the current context:

```
let graphicsContext = NSGraphicsContext(CGContext: context!, flipped:true)
NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
NSGraphicsContext.setCurrentContext(graphicsContext)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Maybe I just suck at making heads or tails of Apple's docs, but I don't know how I would have figured this out on my own. In fact, I'm not even seeing the `NSGraphicsContext(CGContext:flipped:)` method in Apple's docs. The code works and the method is in the header, but not in the docs. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The initializer is not in the docs, that's true. In the Objective C headers, there is `+ (NSGraphicsContext *)graphicsContextWithCGContext:(CGContextRef)graphicsPort flipped:(BOOL)initialFlippedState;` which translates to `NSGraphicsContext(CGContext:flipped:)` in Swift.